# .AndroidStudio2.1 and .AndroidStudio2.2 folders in C

Tags: android-studio

I have Android Studio 2.2.3 installed on a Windows 10 laptop, and I realize that I have 2 related folders in my C drive - .AndroidStudio2.1 and .AndroidStudio2.2.

Since I'm running out of space on my HDD, is it safe to remove the .AndroidStudio2.1 folder?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as you have imported 2.1 settings into 2.2 or decided you don't need them it is safe to remove any .AndroidStudioX folder except the current one, it only holds version/user specific settings